# How to install Eric 6 on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, package-management, eric

I know that this seems like a stupid question, as of course, normally one would run:

```
sudo apt-get install eric
```

as Eric 6 is in the official Ubuntu repositories, but this returned the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 eric : Depends: python3-pyqt5.qsci but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: python3-pyqt5.qtsql but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

trying the recursive mechanism to fix this dependency dilemma, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install eric python3-pyqt5.qsci python3-pyqt5.qtsql python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit python3-pyqt5
```

but this returned the error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pyqt5 is already the newest version (5.5.1+dfsg-3+16.04+build3).
python3-pyqt5 set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 python3-pyqt5.qsci : Depends: libqt5scintilla2-12v5 (>= 2.9) but it is not going to be installed
 python3-pyqt5.qtsql : Depends: python3-pyqt5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4) but 5.5.1+dfsg-3+16.04+build3 is to be installed
 python3-pyqt5.qtwebkit : Depends: python3-pyqt5 (= 5.5.1+dfsg-3ubuntu4) but 5.5.1+dfsg-3+16.04+build3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Have you ever added a PPA for python or other? I just did a simulation in mine and it didn't complain.

Comment: No, I never have.

Comment: Then you definitely have some broken packages/software sources there. Have you already tried the usual *sudo apt install -f* and *sudo dpkg --configure -a*?

Comment: Sure have. Didn't help.

Comment: Most software I can install without a problem, e.g., I installed the games-strategy, games-fps and games-adventure groups without a problem.

Comment: Assuming no errors shown as a result of *sudo apt update*, I would try a different server, just in case. Other than that I'm out of ideas.

Comment: "Held broken packages" usually indicates a *version conflict*, usually caused by PPA or other non-Ubuntu software sources. In this case, the python3-pyqt5 package is coming form a non-Ubuntu source, and it's dependency requirements are likely causing the problem. Disable that source and uninstall *all* software from that non-Ubuntu source.